# read and get xml values in java

Tags: java, xml

i have column data is in XML format with Base64 encryption.i got the values by using java but all values getting i want only particular value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event id="370e7324-3-85ec-63dac16aacb6">
<properties>
<property enc="BASE64" name="state" value="Hrthyw35WmnmewqzRlYXI="/>
<property enc="BASE64" name="record" value="mjhm65WmnmewqzRlYXI="/>    
<property enc="BASE64" name="application" value="Q2FsZWmnmewqzRlYXI="/>
</properties>
</event>
```

and my java code is

```
try {
Query q="select xml from empdata";
String xml = result.getString(1);
System.out.println("----xml----"+xml);
sqlService.dbRead(connection,sql.toString(),new SqlReader() 
{
    @Override       
    public Object readRecord(ResultSet result)
        {
            try {                           
                    String xml = result.getString(1);

                        // read the xml
                        InputSource is = new InputSource();
                        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
                        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("property");
                        String name = null;
                        String value = null;
                        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                            Node node = nList.item(temp);
                            Element element=null;
                            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                element = (Element) node;
                                 name= element.getAttribute("name");
                                 value =  element.getAttribute("value");
                                System.out.println("--value--"+value+"----name----"+name);
                             }
                        }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return null;
        }
});
}catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

i'm getting three names and three values but i want only third name and value.

Comment: Base64 is not encryption, it's an encoding...

Comment: Why don't you use simple if condition like if ("application".equalsIgnoreCase(name)){ //do what you want};

Comment: Why not use Java SE XPath ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the one that has a name of "application"..

You can also simplify your code, there is no need to check the type of the Nodes, getElementsByTagName will only ever return nodes of type Element.

Example

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + "<event id=\"370e7324-3-85ec-63dac16aacb6\">\n"
        + "<properties>\n" + "<property enc=\"BASE64\" name=\"state\" value=\"Hrthyw35WmnmewqzRlYXI=\"/>\n"
        + "<property enc=\"BASE64\" name=\"record\" value=\"mjhm65WmnmewqzRlYXI=\"/>\n"
        + "<property enc=\"BASE64\" name=\"application\" value=\"Q2FsZWmnmewqzRlYXI=\"/>\n" + "</properties>\n"
        + "</event>\n";

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList properties = doc.getElementsByTagName("property");

for (int index = 0; index < properties.getLength(); index++) {
    Node node = properties.item(index);
    Element element = (Element) node;
    if ("application".equals(element.getAttribute("name"))) {
        String name = element.getAttribute("name");
        String valueEncoded = element.getAttribute("value");
        String decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(valueEncoded));
        System.out.println("--value--" + decoded);
    }
}
```

As an alternative to writing your own filtering logic, you can express this with [XPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html), a XML selection language with native Java support.

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
Element element = (Element) xPath.compile("//property[@name=\"application\"]").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
String value = element.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: :String decoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(valueEncoded)); in shows The method getDecoder() is undefined for the type Base64

Comment: it requires any jars?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need 3rd property (Not "application"), you have to count Nodes..

```
var nodeIndex = -1;
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    ...
    if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        nodeIndex++;
        ...
        if (nodeIndex == 2){
            ...
            System.out.println("--value--"+value+"----name----"+name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use JAXB. Most of enterprise applications use JAXB. You could get many tutorials some are below.

1. http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/
2. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-marshal-example/
3. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/12/jaxb-tutorial-xml-binding.html

As, you have not used JAXB, Lets do it with simplest way without using commandline, maven etc.

Step 1: First you would require to make xsd file. There are many online sites where xsd can be generated. Use http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html  for now.
XSD should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="event">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="properties">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="property" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="enc" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Edited: You can also make enc,name and value fields optional. If they are not present it will fine also.

Step 2. Now create a simple java project in eclipse and make sure JDK is present in classpath or library not JRE. otherwise you will get below exception.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.XJCFacade
```

Now, In eclipse Right Click on Property.xsd -->Generate-->JAXB Classes

**NOTE:** If changeing it to jdk doesnt work. Make sure you have JAXB required JARs in you classpath.

Step 3. A new source folder will be created with name generated.Now create A class to read xml.

[image: File Structure of Project]

Your PropertyLoad class should look like below.

```
package generated;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import generated.Event.Properties.Property;

    public class LoadProperties {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {

                File file = new File("src/property.xml");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Event.class);

                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                Event event = (Event) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

                Iterator<Property> itr = event.getProperties().getProperty().iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext()) {
                    Property prop = itr.next();
                    System.out.println(
                            "Encoding : " + prop.getEnc() + "Name  : " + prop.getName() + " Value  : " + prop.getValue());
                }

            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```