# Converting Java generic object to XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to XML payloads like:

```
<ResponseDto>
    <ResponseHeader>
        <success>true</success>
    </ResponseHeader>
    <ResponseBody>
        <ObjectA>
        </ObjectA>
    </ResponseBody>
</ResponseDto>
```

and another payload like:

```
<ResponseDto>
    <ResponseHeader>
        <success>true</success>
    </ResponseHeader>
    <ResponseBody>
        <ObjectB>
        </ObjectB>
    </ResponseBody>
</ResponseDto>
```

so I want to make a class for `ResponseDto` which contains `ResponseHeader Object` and a `generic Java Object` in which I can place different types of objects, so I tried multiple types of Objects in a single class with `@XMLElement(name = "ResponseBody")` but it did not allow me to have same names of `XMLElements`

What can I do in this scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Most of enterprise applications use JAXB. You could get many tutorials some are below.

1. http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/
2. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-marshal-example/
3. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/12/jaxb-tutorial-xml-binding.html

Step 1: First you would require to make xsd file. There are many online sites where xsd can be generated. Use http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html for now. XSD should look like this.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ResponseDto">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ResponseHeader">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="success"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ResponseBody">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ObjectA" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ObjectB" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Refer my below post for reference.
[read and get xml values in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36734959/read-and-get-xml-values-in-java/36738781#36738781)

Comment: Is it possible to do it in java?

Comment: Yes, refer my below link it has detailed explanation.

Comment: only, Trick here is you would require to make element ObjectA and minOccurs = 0 as either one will be present in your case.

Comment: I am currently using JAXB, is there any workaround if I do not want to use xsd file?. By just using annotations?

Comment: Can you share ur code in git or here. Lets see what annotation u are using.

Comment: this code is not giving `ResponseBody` tag when I set one object (let say objectA) at a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111343/discussion-between-pratiyush-kumar-singh-and-mdaniyal).

Comment: Not very helpfull to discuss this in chat. instead of presenting a usefull answere here :(